# How to understand accessing NULL pointer when using in sizeof?

Tags: c

Check this `C` program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        // your code goes here
        char **p = NULL;

        printf("%d,%d\n", sizeof(*p), sizeof(**p));
        return 0;
}
```

Executing the above code, the result is:

```
8,1
```

Although `p` is `NULL`, it doesn't cause program crash in `sizeof(*p)` and `sizeof(**p)`. How to understand this behavior? Is it assured in [c](/questions/tagged/c) spec?

Comment: If you think about what is happening `sizeof(*p)` is just `sizeof (char *)` and `sizeof(**p)` is just `sizeof(char)`

Comment: Warning: UB does not guarantee _crash_, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time. Its operand is not evaluated for side effects, so your program is safe. This is guaranteed by the standard 6.5.3.4/2 (emphasis mine):

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the
>   operand is evaluated; otherwise, **the operand is not evaluated and the
>   result is an integer constant.**

(Note that there is a special case of variable length arrays, in which case the evaluation takes place in run time, so code de-referencing an invalid pointer to a VLA inside sizeof would not be safe.)

As a side note, the correct format specifier for printf when printing the result of `sizeof` is `%zu` (the result of `sizeof` is type `size_t`).

Answer (score 4):

Because `sizeof(exp)` is a compile time operator, and it does not evaluate expression *exp* at run-time.

As a result, there is no dereference of `NULL` pointer at run-time. You just have equivalent machine code of a constant in your `printf` statement in your final binary.

Answer (score 3):

You know `p` is a `char**` so `sizeof(*p) == sizeof(char*)` - no dereference is actually required.

Same applies to `sizeof(**p)` - doesn;t have to do any dereference as it can figure out the size at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The operand of `sizeof` is unevaluated. In other words, `p` is never deferenced, therefore it isn't undefined behavior. On a 64-bit system, a pointer will be 8-bytes wide, and a char is always 1 byte, explaining your output.